# How is the bluetooth low energy pairing method chosen Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a little confused as to what level the Android or peripheral device requests the bluetooth low energy pair request type. Is this in the application layer when I initiate the connection via `device.connectGatt(context, false, gattCallback)` or would this be the job of the peripheral to suggest the type?

How can someone choose between `Just Works`, `Numeric Comparison`, `Passkey Entry` and `Out of Band`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both devices exchange their IOCapabilities at the beginning of the pairing process. The initiator send a IOCapabilityRequest and the responding device answers with a IOCapabilityResponse.

As the name says, the IO Capabilites contain data about what the device can show to the user. This can be one of "Display Only", "Display Yes/No", "Keyboard Only", "NoInputNoOutput", "KeyboardDisplay".

According to what both devices can do, they chose the method, see here:

https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-pairing-part-4

and

https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-pairing-passkey-entry

Comment: Is it possible to have unpaired communication? I initially though 'Just Works' might be the same as unpaired communication but the more I've been reading it seems this is not the case.

Comment: No, Just Works is the name for a pairing procedure where basically the pin is 0000. Usually you need to press a button on both sides to get the pairing / bonding. (Also note that pairing and bonding in the BLE domain mean something slightly different but are actually often used anonymously)